# How to execute awk command with format claming in python script?

Tags: python, awk

The script in python is like below:

```
cmd_3='''cat temp_1.cat | awk -F '[=]' '{printf("%s,",$2);} END {printf("\n");}' '''
call(cmd_3, shell=True)
```

It returns: awk: line 1: runaway string constant " ...

Thanks!

Comment: What does `call()` look like?

Comment: Just solved.Not call but cmd_3 need to be revised.

Comment: That just **can't** be the idiomatic python way to do whatever it is you;re trying to do....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing it as raw string. I have added `"r"` at the start of cmd_3

**Ex:**

```
cmd_3= r'''cat temp_1.cat | awk -F '[=]' '{printf("%s,",$2);} END {printf("\n");}' '''
call(cmd_3, shell=True)
```

Comment: You are welcome. If the above solution solved your problem please accept ans. Thanks